# Vector as entry in `data.table`

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` that looks like this:

```
dt <- data.table(a = 1, b = 1, c = 1)
```

I need column `b` to be treated as an integer vector of variable length, so I can append additional elements to it. For instance, I want to add `2` to column `b` in the first row. I tried

```
dt[a == 1, b := c(b, 2)]
```

but that doesn't work. It gives me a warning:

```
Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(dt, a == 1, `:=`(b, c(b, 2))) :
  Supplied 2 items to be assigned to 1 items of column 'b' (1 unused)
```

What's the right syntax for this?

Comment: Append meaning what?  `b:=b+2` works. `b := paste(b,2, sep = "")` works.

Comment: I need the entry in `b` to be the vector `c(1,2)`.

Comment: Initialize the column as a list and do the assignment: `dt <- data.table(a = 1, b = list(1), c = 1);  dt[[1,2]] <- c(dt[[1,2]],2)`

Comment: This works, but I need to reference the row by the element in column `a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dt <- data.table(a = 1, b = 1:3, c = 1)
dt[, b := .(lapply(b, c, 2))][]
#   a   b c
#1: 1 1,2 1
#2: 1 2,2 1
#3: 1 3,2 1
```

If requiring a conversion to `list` first (i.e. when not already a `list`, and subsetting or doing a `by`), add `dt[, b := .(as.list(b))]` before the above.

Comment: This doesn't work for the given example i.e. I tried `dt <- data.table(a = 1, b = 1, c = 1); dt[, b := lapply(b, c, 2)][]`, and I get the same warning message as in my question.